# Let $l\not =\infty$ then $l=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$ if and only if...

Tags: real-analysis

Let $l\not =\infty$ then $l=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$ if and only if $\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that if $n>N$ then $x_n<l+\epsilon$ and $\forall \epsilon>0\forall m\in\mathbb{N}\exists N>m$ such that $x_n>l-\epsilon$

**My attempt:**
Let $\epsilon>0$
$(\implies)$ By hypothesis we know $l=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n$.

We know $$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n={\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}}_{k\geq n}x_n\leq l$$

then exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $Sup_{k\geq n}x_n<l+\epsilon$ for each $n\geq N$.

This implies:

$x_n<l+\epsilon$

> is correct this?
>
> for the other implication i dont have a clear idea. can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\implies$ Your idea is correct. I would express it as follows: since $l=\limsup_nx_n=\lim_n\sup_{k\geqslant n}x_k$, you know that $\sup_{k\geqslant n}x_k<l+\varepsilon$ if $n\geqslant N$, for some $N\in\mathbb N$. But then $x_n<l+\varepsilon$ if $n\geqslant N$.

$\Longleftarrow$ It can't be proved since it is false. Actually, for any number $l>\limsup_nx_n$ that condition will also hold, although $l\neq\limsup_na_n$.

Comment: Thanks, i edit my question. Because for the other implication i had a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is as good as correct. If this is a homework problem you might want to explain why in particular such an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ exists.

For the reverse implication, note that the first part implies that the row is bounded upwards. This ensures the suprema of the row will all be non-infinity and form a decreasing real row $s_n$ (why?), with $s_n := \sup\{x_i |i \geq n \}$.

The second part, combined with the fact that $s_n$ is decreasing, implies in particular that $s_n \geq l - 1$ (why? Assuming the contrary should quickly lead to a contradiction).

Therefore, the row $s_n$ is bounded downwards and decreasing. It must therefore have a non-infinity limit. Assuming this limit is larger than $l$ will lead to a contradiction using the first condition; assuming this limit is smaller than $l$ will lead to a contradiction using the second condition.

Feel free to ask for more clarification.

Comment: Thanks, i edit my question. Because for the other implication i had a mistake

Comment: Edited the answer.